# c# - how to add an xml field with multiple values to a dictionary

Tags: c#, xml

I wrote a C# code that would convert a xml field and its value to a dictionary, but what I did not notice was that the XML files I was receiving had some fields that contained multiple values(ConditionAncestorTerm) as in the next block:

```
<StudyFieldsResponse>
<APIVrs>1.01.02</APIVrs>
  <DataVrs>2020:12:06 23:30:13.949</DataVrs>
  <Expression>ca045-011</Expression>
  <NStudiesAvail>359831</NStudiesAvail>
  <NStudiesFound>1</NStudiesFound>
  <MinRank>1</MinRank>
  <MaxRank>20</MaxRank>
  <NStudiesReturned>1</NStudiesReturned>
  <FieldList>
    <Field>CompletionDate</Field>
    <Field>Condition</Field>
    <Field>ConditionAncestorTerm</Field>
  </FieldList>
  <StudyFieldsList>
    <StudyFields Rank="1">
      <FieldValues Field="CompletionDate">
        <FieldValue>January 17, 2026</FieldValue>
      </FieldValues>
      <FieldValues Field="Condition">
        <FieldValue>Renal Cell Carcinoma</FieldValue>
      </FieldValues>
      <FieldValues Field="ConditionAncestorTerm">
        <FieldValue>Neoplasms, Glandular and Epithelial</FieldValue>
        <FieldValue>Neoplasms by Histologic Type</FieldValue>
        <FieldValue>Neoplasms</FieldValue>
        <FieldValue>Adenocarcinoma</FieldValue>
        <FieldValue>Kidney Neoplasms</FieldValue>
        <FieldValue>Urologic Neoplasms</FieldValue>
        <FieldValue>Urogenital Neoplasms</FieldValue>
        <FieldValue>Neoplasms by Site</FieldValue>
        <FieldValue>Kidney Diseases</FieldValue>
        <FieldValue>Urologic Diseases</FieldValue>
      </FieldValues>
```

My C# code to convert the XML elements to a dictionary looked like this at first:

```
static Dictionary<string, string> DecodeXML(XDocument study)
        {
            // Convert XML to a dictionary
            var data = study
                .Elements("StudyFieldsResponse")
                .Elements("StudyFieldsList")
                .Elements("StudyFields")
                .Elements("FieldValues")
                .ToDictionary(
                    key => key.Attribute("Field").Value,
                    value => value.Element("FieldValue").Value
                    );

            return data;
        }
```

My code breaks now, because some fields have multiple values and I'm guessing the program doesn't take that well.
I want to be able to add all those values corresponding to one field into a list, so I was thinking I should change the dictionary to a <string, List> to make it work but I haven't found a way to store every single value into the list.
Does anyone know how I could approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following :

```
           XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            Dictionary<string, XElement> dict = doc.Descendants("FieldValues")
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Attribute("Field"), y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
```

---

Or this

```
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict = doc.Descendants("FieldValues")
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Attribute("Field"), y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Elements("FieldValue").Select(z => (string)z).ToList());
```

Comment: Thanks, the second answer does the job! I didn't really understand the first block. Does that only grab the first value? since it says y.FirstorDefault()?

Comment: The first solution gets the FieldValues and all the children.

Answer (score 0):

first load the xml and then create the dictionary

`

```
var xml= XDocument.Load("XMLFileName.xml");

    var data= xml.Document.Root.Elements("StudyFieldsResponse")
                        .Elements("StudyFieldsList")
                        .Elements("StudyFields")
                        .Elements("FieldValues")
                        .ToDictionary(
                              x => x.Attribute("Field").Value,
                              x => x.Elements("FieldValue")
                        .Select(y => y.Value)
                        .ToArray());
```

`

It would be more helpful if you share the output you want to display.